# Make change out of a set of change, recursively

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set which I construct recursively.

First, take the set $\{1,2,\dots,m\}$ and select $n$ elements, with replacement, uniformly at random.

For example, if $n=3$, you could pick $\{1,2,2\}$.

This set is then "accumulated" via the (three) "partial sums", to give $\{1, 1+2, 1+2+2\} = \{1,3,5\} $, which is the new set.

If the set had been $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$, the accumulation would be $\{a_1,a_1 +a_2,\dots,a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n\}$

One then repeats. So, select now $o$ random coins from $\{1,3,5\} $, with replacement, e.g. $\{1,1,3,5\}$ should we set $o=4$, then accumulate to get $\{1,2,5,10\}$. Then select $p$ random coins with replacement, and continue.

**How can I describe the set (in set builder notation, or otherwise) of all possible sets I may end up with, after $N$ iterations, in terms of the fixed, initial integer parameters $m,n,o,p\dots$ and so on?**

Initially, I am selecting a random partition of an integer between $0$ and $m \times n$. Then I am building an integer partition out of the partial sums of the parts of that partition (i.e. a restricted integer partition, but of a number less than $m \times n \times o$).